# Datetimestamp not working

Tags: php, sql, database, date, time

In my MYSQL Database. I have a 'Date' and 'Time' type. When I input data into the SQL table. I'd like the time to show what time the data was submitted. I've looked around and found nothing.

If someone could tell me how I can fix this much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you have tried, show some code.

Comment: @FrayneKonok Hi. It's in the database so no code. Do you want the code in which I submit the data into the database?

Comment: both, the PHP and table structure.

Comment: My table structure. http://imgur.com/UQU90Dz

Comment: looks like you are use `Current_timestamp` in your `dateTimestamp` filed. so what now you want to do?

Comment: do you want to separate the date, time to show in your php page?

Comment: http://imgur.com/sX2v42u The date needs to be 0000-00-00 and time needs to be 00:00:00. Not in the same column.

Comment: do you want to do it in PHP no MySQl?

Comment: What ever works. I think SQL is easier for what I'm trying to do,

Comment: as you accept your answer i left the discussion here. but PHP may help you to format and separate date and time.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter your db table schema, here is how you can change by phpmyadmin

[image]

Or by query you can do like this

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` CHANGE `date_created` `date_created` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for one column. I have a datetimestamp and a timestamp. Ideas?  http://imgur.com/UQU90Dz

Answer (score 0):

Okey, after a complete discussion. you want to insert a datetime in a timestamp filed, but want ot show the date and time different in your PHP code.

The date function convert a microtime to any custom format of date, time.
and the strtotime convert the time to mictotime.

**Try this:**

In PHP just use
$Datetimestamp = //fetch the timestamp field

This is for Date: `date("Y-m-d" , strtotime($Datetimestamp))`

and this is for time: `date("H:i:s" , strtotime($Datetimestamp))`